# Put server on heavy load for testing

Tags: linux, unix

I'm doing some testing on a Linux server and I need the server to be on a heavy load.  I was wondering how I would simulate this? Right now the server goes upto 20% CPU but I need to force it to around 80% and do some testing to see how it copes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to force CPU's occupation, try this :

```
for cpu in 1 2 ; do
   ( while true; do true; done ) &
done
```

If you want to simualte IO charge too, try with this :

```
for cpu in 1 2 ; do
   ( while true; do find / -type f -exec cp {} /dev/null \; ; done ) &
done
```

with `for cpu in 1 2` for 2 cores, `for cpu in 1 2 3 4` for 4 cores ;)

Comment: I'm guessing this does some searching or something in dev/null ?

Comment: the `find` command with those arguments are copying every file in the filesystem to `/dev/null`, so generating a lot of IO as @Cédric said.

Comment: Certainly works although i'm abit worried with the copying of files to /dev/null.  The files don't actually get permanently stored in /dev/null right?

Comment: @unleashed no, `/dev/null` is some kind of black-hole or sink. Anything you store in there just disappears, and does not use a single byte of your hard disk space.

Comment: find generates a lot of file system i/o. But @unleashed like to know, how to rise the CPU usage much as possible. So don't use filesystem-components for that, because the CPU generates filesystem-wait-i/o which is not the same as CPU usage.

Comment: @The Bndr : my first loop burn only CPU, my second loop burn IO (if your filesystem are in a RAMFS, it will burn some CPU too), if you want to burn CPU and IO, launch the 2 loops in parallel ;)

Comment: @Cédric Julien Sorry, I did an mistake be reading your post. So: everything is fine. Sorry. :-)

Comment: To kill them, use `kill %1 %2`, replacing the numbers with the ones printed at the beginning of the lines when starting the jobs.

Comment: Copying a file to /dev/null overwrites /dev/null.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for generating cpu usage, so you have to choose commands, which are CPU intensive.
For example generation random-numbers.

Try this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null
```

Add on of those line for every CPU core. If you have an dual-core CPU use:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null &
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null &
```

Check the jobs with

```
jobs
```

End the jobs with
`kill %1` (where %1 is the number of job 1)