# Put server on heavy load for testing in Windows

Tags: windows, server, command-prompt

Need to heavily exercise an eight-core server under Windows. Found a Linux exercising test at [Put server on heavy load for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056097/put-server-on-heavy-load-for-testing) and would like to perform a similar workout using command prompt commands.

Comment: take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924742.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Drat.  oemstress no longer included with the current version, version 6.

Answer (score -2):

Solved: I created a batch file DO.BAT which contains one line

`dir /s /r /on & do ^z`

and then from within a command prompt window entered

`start do`

which opened a new command prompt window and launched DO.BAT to loop until a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> is entered. Then, repeated that until many windows were running.

Many thanks to *Bali C* who mentioned the start command in [How to run multiple DOS commands in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010834/how-to-run-multiple-dos-commands-in-parallel)